# Check if browser supports SVG for mobile devices, preferably Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, svg

I am trying to develop a web application for mobile devices (Android and iPhone).
I came to know that Android older version browser doesn't support SVG.

Is there a way in JavaScript, jQuery (whatever, in fact) to check if browser supports SVG? So, if it doesn't support I might be able to do some "B" Code for my app to run properly for all browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which SVG support detection method is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689310/which-svg-support-detection-method-is-best)

Answer (score 4):

Simple, [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), which supports mobile browsers too.

Comment: Modernizr does detect svg. Read the docs here www.modernizr.com/docs/

Answer (score 3):

I would personally do something like this:

```
var supportsSVG = false;
try{
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
  supportsSVG = typeof svg.createSVGPoint == 'function';
}catch(e){}
```

If it can create an SVG element, and that SVG element has a `createSVGPoint` function, then I'd bet that it supports SVG.

*Or better yet, try to create and test some of the exact features you want. I have a [list of SVG 1.1 objects/properties/methods](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/hierarchy) on my site; find the object you try to create, find it, and see if it has the methods you need.*

Comment: The best way to check something is supported is to check *if its supported*