# Which SVG support detection method is best?

Tags: javascript, svg, browser-feature-detection

Somebody has already [asked my question about detecting SVG support in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654112/how-do-you-detect-support-for-vml-or-svg-in-a-browser) but there are three leading solutions and not a lot of discussion about the merits of each.

So: which, if any, is best? In terms of portability and correctness, that is. False negatives (i.e. "no svg") are undesirable, but acceptable; false positives are not.

Exhibit A:

```
var testImg = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNzUiIGhlaWdodD0iMjc1Ij48L3N2Zz4%3D';

var img = document.createElement('img')

img.setAttribute('src',testImg);

return img.complete;
```

Exhibit B:

```
return document.implementation.hasFeature(
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BasicStructure", "1.1");
```

Exhibit C:

```
return !! document.createElementNS &&
       !! document.createElementNS (
             'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
             "svg")
      .createSVGRect;
```

Comment: What are your fitness criteria for 'best'? Perhaps you should modify your question and title to ask specific, answerable questions like _"Will any of these fail (return a false negative or positive) in any browsers released in the last 3 years?"_ or some such. Otherwise this question is ripe for closing as subjective.

Comment: Exhibit B is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Comment: Looks like that's the same as C underneath.

Comment: Not a very useful answer, unless you care to explain which method modernizr uses and why it is better. Feature detection need not rely on a library, and the library must use some sort of detection itself.

Answer (score 40):

No need to include the entire Modernizr library for this. Here's a simple check that I've used in the past:

```
typeof SVGRect !== "undefined"; // true if supported, false if not
```

This quite simply checks for support of the `SVGRect` object which is defined in the [SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGRect). In Chrome, `typeof SVGRect` is `"function"` and in IE9 it's `"object"`, but in browsers which do not support SVG (IE8, for instance) this returns `"undefined"`.

With the above code, you can simply:

```
if (typeof SVGRect !== "undefined") { ... /* If the browser does support SVG. */ }
else { ... /* If the browser does not support SVG. */ }
```

Comment: Is this an accurate test for determining if the browser supports svg within an img tag? `<img src="file.svg">`? Are there browsers that support svg images via `img src`, while also NOT supporting the modern API for programmatically  drawing them?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Modernizr uses approach B to detect for support for SVGs in `<img>` tags, and approach C to detect for support for SVGs in `<embed>` and `<object>` tags. It seems it used to use an approach that was more like A for detecting for "SVG as img" support, but that was dropped in favour of B (for more detail, see [this post](http://css-tricks.com/test-support-svg-img/) on CSS-tricks).

Consequently, it seems that at the moment, either B or C would be the best approach, depending on what exactly you want to test for.