# SVG image on mobile device isn't displaying properly

Tags: html, mobile, svg, responsive

I have just added an SVG image to my personal website for the logo but when I view the image on my mobile device it's displaying, but in a different font. That's my problem. How do I fix this?

The way I am adding the SVG is as I would a normal image.

```
<img src="images/logo.svg">
```

I have a feeling this is not the correct way to add SVG images, I also have no fallback for browsers that do not support SVG so if anyone could offer advice on how to do that, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You could always take a screen shot of the SVG and edit it in a paint editor to make it PNG

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to keep it SVG for retina displays and create fallbacks for browsers/devices that do not support SVG images. I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689310/which-svg-support-detection-method-is-best) it goes over SVG capability checks. You can probably tweak the JavaScript to change the image it's trying to display if it can't support SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying SVG images using `<img>` has quite good browser support nowadays: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img so I personally would recommend it.

If you need to support very old browsers like IE8 or Android 2.3, I would use

```
document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image", "1.1")
```

to check for feature detection (source: https://css-tricks.com/test-support-svg-img/) and use a PNG file then (by replacing the `src` attribute of the `<img>`).

To include a custom font in a SVG, one can include it in the SVG's `<def>`:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Gunny Rewritten';
      src: url('GunnyRewritten.woff');
    }
  </style>
</defs>
```

Comment: Do you still have a question regarding this issue? If not, don't hesitate to accept it. :-)

Comment: Sorry I have been away at the weekend. I'm still trying to solve this problem, yes. I'm wondering if the problem is that i'm using a font that isn't supported by the browser; which is "Gunny Rewritten". It's also not on google fonts so I can't embed it in the SVG code. 

As I said, the SVG displays correctly using any desktop browser, it's just when I use google on my iPhone 6 or Safari.

Comment: If the font is non-standard nor embedded, the browser cannot display it. It may be displayed if your local system has the font installed, but nowhere else. If you have a valid license for the font, you should embed it.

Comment: How would I go about embedding the font? I'd rather not change the font you see.

Comment: With css. Define the font resource in a `<style>` tag in `<defs>` of your svg:  `<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Gunny Rewritten';
      src: url('GunnyRewritten.woff');
    }
  </style>
</defs>`

Comment: It still isn't happening for me, it displays fine on desktop browsers.. it's hosted on a server so I don't see why it works there and not on the iPhone browsers. 

I have added that line you suggested ^ ...should that work, or do I need to change the SRC url?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it, it's only an example. It should contain the correct path to your web font file on your server.

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the extended help! Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you create .svg from Ilustrator (e.g), first, be sure to create outlines from your text object, then, export object to .svg file, wich will be read from any (modern) browser.